# Ionic v4 - how do I autofocus on a Input?

Tags: ionic4, autofocus

I have a view with an input `<ion-input #codigobarras></ion-input>`

How can I auto focus on this input?

## What have I tried

```
@ViewChild('codigobarras') input_codigobarras: Input;

...

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.input_codigobarras.focus(); // didn't work = temp2.focus is not a function
    this.input_codigobarras.focus.emit(); // didn't work = do nothing, just returns undefined
    this.input_codigobarras.getElementRef().nativeElement.focus() // didn't work = do nothing, just returns undefined
    this.input_codigobarras.setFocus(); // didn't work = do nothing, just returns undefined
}
```

```
<ion-input [autofocus]></ion-input> <!-- Didn't work -->
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work

```
<ion-input autofocus="true"></ion-input>
```

Comment: That worked, but after the pages loads I have loading on screen while I list some itens, this loading blurs the input, do you know how can I focus again after this loading?

Comment: Maybe you can try my answer 2

Answer (score 14):

A more generic solution to do this when and where you want could be:

```
<ion-input ... #inputId></ion-input>
```

So with a `ViewChild` in your controller you can easily set the focus on:

```
@ViewChild('inputId', {static: false}) ionInput: { setFocus: () => void; };
...
setFocusOnInput() {
   this.ionInput.setFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had an conflict of focus regarding with ion-input inside a ion-modal. In fact, after using a timeout, i realized that my ion-input was focus and unfocused instantly.

> setTimeout(() => this.ionInput.setFocus(), 100);

So, I console log the activeElement (the one that is focused) with:

> document.activeElement

And the console output ion-modal.

Hence, I had to wait the ion-modal to be "fully loaded" to use the setFocus with as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

After the loading of your items you can try to trigger your ElementRef with ngOnChanges()

```
 @ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
     if(changes.items) {
     this.test.nativeElement.firstChild['autofocus'] = 'true';
   }
}
```

and your html

```
<div #test>
  <ion-input ></ion-input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 4/5**

**HTML**

```
<ion-input ... #inputId></ion-input>
```

**TS**

```
export class SomePage {
....
@ViewChild('inputId', {static: false}) inputEl: IonInput;
....

focusOnElement() {
    this.tipDesc.setFocus();
}
```

**Ionic 3**

```
@ViewChild('inputId') inputEl: TextInput;
```

Call **focusOnElement()** when you want to focust on input

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Ionic 6 : 


  HTML :
    <ion-input type="text" #autofocus>
    
    TS File : 
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    
    @ViewChild('autofocus', { static: false }) inputBox!: IonInput;
    
    ionViewWillEnter() {
        setTimeout(() => this.inputBox.setFocus(), 300);
      }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those whom are facing the same problem in Ionic with React.

I tried both inputRef.current.focus() and set autofocus=true without success.

inputRef.current.setFocus() instead works.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML CODE:

```
<ion-input #inputId></ion-input>
```

TS CODE:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {  IonInput } from '@ionic/angular';
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('inputId', {  static: false })  inputElement: IonInput;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.inputElement.setFocus();
    }, 400);
  }`
```